# Customize the location of the persistent store of a UIManagedDocument

Tags: core-data, location, store, uimanageddocument

Is it possible to customize the location of the persistent store file of a UIManagedDocument?  Normally, UIManagedDocument imposes the following document structure:

Document package
- StoreContent
-- persistentStore

I need the structure to be:

Document package
- persistentStore

Basically, I want to remove the need for the "StoreContent" directory.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done that yet but it might be possible by creating a custom subclass of `UIManagedDocument` and overwrite

```
configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:ofType:modelConfiguration:storeOptions:error:
```

with setting the `storeURL` to your custom one.

From the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIManagedDocument/configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL%3aofType%3amodelConfiguration%3astoreOptions%3aerror%3a):

> You can override this method if you want customize the creation or loading of the document’s persistent store. For example, you can perform post-migration clean-up—if your application needs to migrate store data to use a new version of the managed object model, you can override this method to make additional modifications to the store after migration.